# No local variables, but warning: referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, local-variables

I have a simple exercise using PyCharm community editor, and I get a warning:

> This inspection warns about local variables referenced before
>   assignment.

But there is no local variable here, and also it works well on Windows PowerShell. What's wrong with it?

```
# This is a guess the number game.
import random
secret_number = random.randint(1, 21)
print("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20. You have three chances.")

# Ask the player to guess 3 times.
for guesses_taken in range(1, 4):
    guess = int(input('Take a guess.\n'))
    if guess > secret_number:
        print('Your guess is too high.')
    elif guess < secret_number:
        print('Your guess is to low.')
    elif guess == secret_number:
        if guesses_taken == 1:
            print('Oh my god. You just guessed only one time.')
        else:
            print("You are right. I'm thinking of %s, and you guessed my 
                number in %s guesses." % (secret_number, guesses_taken))
    else:
        break
if guess != secret_number:  --> # Name 'guess' can be not defined.
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + str(secret_number) + '.')
```

Similarly, the revised version here still has the same problem.

```
# This is a guess the number game.
import random
secret_number = random.randint(1, 21)
print("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20. You have three chances.")

# Ask the player to guess 3 times.
for guesses_taken in range(1, 4):
    guess = int(input('Take a guess.\n'))
    if guess > secret_number:
        print('Your guess is too high.')
    elif guess < secret_number:
        print('Your guess is to low.')
    else:
        break
if guess == secret_number:  --> # Name 'guess' can be not defined
    if guesses_taken == 1:  --> # Name 'guesses_taken' can be not defined
        print('Oh my god. You just guessed only one time.')
    else:
        print("You are right. I'm thinking of %s, and you guessed my number in %s guesses." % (
            secret_number, guesses_taken))
else:
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + str(secret_number) + '.')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get *warnings*: they don't mean that your code won't work as expected, but they mean to tell you that things *could go wrong* under certain circomstances.

I don't use PyCharm, but the reasons I see for these warnings are:

- `guess` gets assigned inside your `for` loop. So, in case the loop doesn't execute at least once, `guess` would never be assigned.
- `guesses_taken` will first be assigned the first value of the `range`, then the second... But if the `range` were to be empty, it would also never get assigned.

See, for example:

```
for loop_index in range(1, -1):  # empty! 
    my_value_assigned_in_loop = 1

print(loop_index)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-39f9878362fc> in <module>()
      2     my_value_assigned_in_loop = 1
      3 
----> 4 print(loop_index)

NameError: name 'loop_index' is not defined
```

Comment: **Thanks for your help.** But, is this problem in the programming process allowed, or will it bring more unexpected trouble?

Comment: No, your program is perfectly fine, because your loop is certain to execute. The rules PyCharm uses to give you warnings probably don't take that into account and only rely on the general structure of the code. There are anyway limits at what one can do without really executing it. So, no trouble ahead!

Comment: **Extremely grateful**